# Swift closure defindet as class property cannot access other class properies

Tags: swift, closures

When directly assigning / implementing a Swift closure it is no problem to access class properties. But when I try to define the closure as class propertie as well, access to other class properties is not possible. **Why is this?**

---

**Here is an example:**

While the closure directly assigned to `editorVC.completionBlock` can access the class property `tableView` without any problem, the same code within leads to an error when the closure is defined as class property `editorCompletionBlock`:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    func showEditor(withData: String) {
        let editorVC = EditorViewController()

        // Directly assign closure - Works without any problem
        editorVC.completionBlock = { (result) in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            doSomething(withResult: result)
            // ...
        }
        present(editorVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Define closure as class property ==> Error
    let editorCompletionBlock: EditorCompletionBlock = { (resut) in
        // ERROR: Value of type '(MyViewController) -> () -> MyViewController' has no member 'tableView'
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        doSomething(withResult: result)
        // ...
    }
}


typealias EditorCompletionBlock = (String) -> Void

class EditorViewController: UIViewController {
    var completionBlock: EditorCompletionBlock?

    func closeEditor(withResult result: String) {
        completionBlock?(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason:**

You can't access `self` until the *initialization process* of a type is completed.

In your code, `editorCompletionBlock` is a *stored property* and you're trying to access `self.tableView` inside it. This is the reason it is giving compile time error.

**Solution:**

Instead, make `editorCompletionBlock` as a `lazy` property to get that working.

```
lazy var editorCompletionBlock: EditorCompletionBlock = { (result) in
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    doSomething(withResult: result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

place your **`editorCompletionBlock`** in **`viewDidLoad`(:_)** and it should work like charm:

```
    class MyViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
        func showEditor(withData: String) {
            let editorVC = EditorViewController()
    
            editorVC.completionBlock = { (result) in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            present(editorVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let editorCompletionBlock: EditorCompletionBlock = { (resut) in
                self.tableView.reloadData() ///should work :)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    typealias EditorCompletionBlock = (String) -> Void
    
    class EditorViewController: UIViewController {
        var completionBlock: EditorCompletionBlock?
    
        func closeEditor(withResult result: String) {
            completionBlock?(result)
        }
    }
```

**Solution 2:**
Or you can just declare your closure as **`lazy`**:

```
lazy var editorCompletionBlock: EditorCompletionBlock = { (result) 
      in
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    doSomething(withResult: result)
}
```